# How to convert a pcap file to am ASC or BLF file?

Tags: python-can

I want to convert a pcap file to asc or blf file. I am new to the field and I appreciate your

answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Technica-Engineering/Technica.Traces.Blf.Converter, libraries used there could be used to do what you want.